# Avoid data redundancy in ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net page which uses a listview to show 2 columns of data.
The first column has just labels and the second one has dropdowns.

My concern is, the dropdowns in second column has same items 100% of the time, they never change and since it is databound, and datasource to these dropdown is also same. As these dropdowns are in a list view this repetition happens on each row added to my list view!

So, I was thinking of removing this data redundancy being transported over the wire. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a question about improving UI, reducing the amount of data sent from your server to your user or the number of database calls (assuming your dropdown is bound to a database result set)?

Comment: @AndyC: Yes, you are right. I am trying to reduce the page load time. The idea I have is the old school one, to avoid using databound dropdowns and write some fancy javascript to do the job. but open to a new/better suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

If your datasource is a database call then you can reduce that by storing the result of the call in a `DataView` object, and then binding your dropdowns to that object rather than making the call to the database for each dropdown.

Comment: That was the first thing, I did already. Now I am also thinking on reducing the duplicate data being sent over internet!

Comment: Is your query optimised for databinding? Are you only selecting the fields you need (ie one field for value and one field for display member) ? You aren't selecting unused fields, right?

Comment: Yes, that is taken care of :-)

Comment: The items in databound dropdown are close to 1000 and are repeated for each dropdown

Comment: Sounds like you need to re-think your UI. Is there a way you can re-work it so the dropdown is only on the page once?

Comment: that is what I have as a consideration currently, or probably use a list(and of course load it only once) and do some fancy javascript to show it against textboxes(which I intend to replace for dropdowns). Reminds me of old ASP/HTML/JS days :)

Comment: Since you have suggested a re-think for UI. Any suggestions from your end?

Comment: Sorry, hard to know without actually having all the details.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an ObjectDataSource, you can reduce the load time [enabling the cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.enablecaching.aspx):

```
   <asp:objectdatasource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server"
      EnableCaching="true" .... >
   </asp:objectDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following approach:

It loads the items in to the very first DropDownList and then uses JQuery to retrieve that DropDownList and and replicate the items into all of the others.

**Markup**

```
<div id="listViewContainer">
    <asp:ListView ID="listView1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div><asp:DropDownList ID="dropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>        
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$(function () {
    var sourceDropDown = $('#listViewContainer').find('select').first();

    $('#listViewContainer').find('select').not(sourceDropDown).each(function () {
        var dropdown = $(this);
        dropdown.find('option').remove();

        sourceDropDown.find('option').each(function () {
            var option = $(this);
            dropdown.append($('<option />').text(option.text()).val(option.val()));
        });
    });
});
```

**Code**

```
    void listView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.DisplayIndex == 0)
        {
            DropDownList dropDownList1 = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("dropDownList1");
            dropDownList1.DataSource = dataTable;
            dropDownList1.DataTextField = "Text";
            dropDownList1.DataValueField = "Value";
            dropDownList1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.